# Error connecting to broker: PulsarClientException Connection Refused

Tags: apache-pulsar

We saw this exception in our Pulsar client app:

> Error connecting to broker:
> org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException:
> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
> org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
> finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused:
> myserver.mycompany.com/10.20.10.15:6651

It only randomly occurs. We can't find a way to reproduce it despite testing different client settings. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when the Pulsar broker the client is connected to is restarted.

Pulsar clients connect directly to the broker that is handling the topic the client is using. If that broker is restarted, the connection is broken, and that broker's topics will be unloaded and moved to other brokers. When the client reconnects, it should connect to the broker that is the new owner of that topic, and communication should resume as expected. Since this exception can occur occasionally, you can either handle the exception (e.g. with try/catch), or you can fail fast and force your app to restart, which will also re-establish the connection. I usually recommend failing fast to ensure the exception shows up in logs in case there are concerns around the incident.